# PHP Function for Item in Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array that is being created from database results. It contains a list of "views" that are allowed on the UI based on permissions.

I am trying to create a function that I can pass a view to and it will tell me if it exists in the array.

My Array:

```
[views] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [keys] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [view] => viewOriginalFeedback
                            )

                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [view] => viewTarget
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

My PHP Function:

```
function getViews($val) {

    // Define as global
    global $perms;

    // Loop over array
    foreach ($perms as $item){
        if (isset($item['view']) && $item['view'] == $val){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

echo getViews('viewTarget');
```

It never returns anything in my echo statement.

Notice anything obvious I have missed?

**Update:** My array starts at `KEYS` `$perms = $permissions->data->views->keys;`

**UPDATE 2**
This seems to have fixed it. I had to move the `return false;` outside of the IF statement so it wasn't over written by true values.

```
function getViews($val) {

    // Define as global
    global $perms;

    // Loop over array
    foreach ($perms as $item){
        if (isset($item->view) && $item->view == $val){
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Since it is an object, have you tried -> `if (isset($item->view) && $item->view == $val){`?

Comment: That didnt seem to work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if your array is passed exactly as you show, but if it is then try this:

```
 function getViews($val) {

     // Define as global
     global $perms;

     // Loop over array
     foreach ($perms['keys'] as $item){
         if (isset($item['view']) && $item['view'] == $val){
             return true;
         }

     }
     return false; }
```